# error C4430: missing type specifier / error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am getting both errors on the same line. Bridge *first in the Lan class. What am i missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Lan{
    Bridge *first;
    Bridge *second;
    Host hostList[10];
    int id;
};

class Bridge{
    Lan lanList[5];
};




class Host{
    Lan * lan;
    int id;
public:
    Host(int newId)
    {
        id=newId;
    }
};



void main(){

return;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `Bridge` before `Lan`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Bridge;

class Lan{
    Bridge *first;
    Bridge *second;
    Host hostList[10];
    int id;
};

class Bridge{
    Lan lanList[5];
};
```

Comment: +1. But next problem will be the Host *definition*, required for Lan :)

Comment: so it's all about declarations. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the forward declaration for `Bridge`. Otherwise when compiling `Lan` class compiler doesn't know what `Bridge*` is. You should tell the compiler that `Bridge` is a class which you are going to define later. Forward declare it as `class Bridge;` before `class Lan`

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `class Bridge;` before the declaration of the Lan class.

Answer (score 1):

`Bridge` is not defined at the moment it is used.

you need a forward declaration so that the compiler knows that `Bridge` is a valid class name. before the `Lan` class, write:

```
class Bridge;
```

Answer (score 1):

Bridge doesn't exist until after the Lan declaration.  you should forward-declare Bridge.  besides that, Lan won't compile because Host is not known either, and forward declaration won't help, because the compiler needs to know Host's size.